# Rails activerecord where in get results in specific order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

```
ids = [15, 7, 50]
results = Model.where(id: ids)
```

the results would be model with id 7, 15, 50 in this order, how can i get results by the order of id in ids (15, 7, 50) ?

Comment: check out this answer https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/59401/198877

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're several ways.
Easiest database-independent way is to sort in ruby after fetch:

```rb
order = ids.each_with_index.to_h
results.sort_by{|item| order[item.id] }
```

note that that requires fetching whole result into memory and returns an array, which may have some implications depending on your app

In Mysql you can use `order by field(id, ...)`:

```rb
Model.where(...).order("field(id, #{ids.join(',')})")`
```

In postgres 9.5+ - `order by array_position(array[...], id)`:

```rb
Model.where(...).order("array_position(array[#{ids.join(',')}], id)")`
```

Comment: Worth noting that `sort_by` will return an `Array` whereas `order` will return an `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

Comment: @muistooshort you're correct, not needed here, `array_position` is more suitable

Comment: I had to encapsulate `.order` body to `Arel.sql(..)` otherwise I was getting `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeReference (Query method called with non-attribute argument(s)` error in Rails 6.4.1.